# Placing Variables in Google map Script tag

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am trying to put a Google direction map to my page. The JS  element is defined as below. As of the moment this is hard coded but I need to make the origin (Miami,FL) , destination (Buffalo,NY) and waypoints to be dynamic. I am getting the location strings from a Json from back-end using angular's http.get.

My question how can I make the origin, destination and waypoint to be dynamic?

```
<script>
  function initMap() {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    center: {lat: 41.85, lng: -87.65},
    scrollwheel: false,
    zoom: 7
  });

  var directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer({
    map: map
  });

  // Set destination, origin and travel mode.
  var request = {
    destination: "Miami, FL",
    origin: "Buffalo, NY",
    travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING,
    waypoints: [
    {
      location:"Richmond, VA",
      stopover:true
    },{
      location:"Washington, DC",
      stopover:true
    }],
};

var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();

directionsService.route(request, function(response, status) {
if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
  directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
  }
 });
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example of the JSON array. In this example the array is declared in the js scope, however you should be accessing you array in a different way, I would assume with ajax. Both ways, you will be arrange the rest of the code as needed.

Array declaration:

```
var placesJSON = 
  [   
 {
     "location":"Richmond, VA",
      stopover:true

 },
  {
      "location":"Washington, DC",
      "stopover":true

  },
  {
      "location":"Atlanta",
      "stopover":true

  }
  ];
```

dynamic variables:

```
var request = {
    destination: "Miami, FL",
    origin: "Buffalo, NY",
    travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING,
    waypoints: [
    {
      location:placesJSON[0].location,
      stopover:placesJSON[0].stopover
    },{
      location:placesJSON[2].location,
      stopover:placesJSON[2].stopover
    }],
};
```

Here is the fiddle example:
https://jsfiddle.net/eugensunic/45n45cpd/1/

If you want to access you JSON array by a specific name (not by index). Then I suggest to loop trough an array and create an if statement for example

```
if(desired_destination== placesJSON[index].location){// select this places}
```

to confirm your request.

Comment: thanks for the answer, not a direct answer but I got an idea from here. thanks again!